# How to check if a ray intersects a circle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, python, programming

Given a ray (Origin(x,y) and Direction(x,y)) and a circle (Center(x,y) and Radius) determine if the ray intersects the circle (touches one or two points in the circle).

I've followed [this](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-sphere-intersection) solution (both geometic and analityc) but I can't get it to work on my python code. Anyone can see my mistake?

The code is the following:

```
def dot(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return (x1*x2) + (y1*y2)


def intersects(x, y, vx, vy, cx, cy, r):
# r is radius, x and y are the ray origin, vx and vy are the ray direction and cx and cy are the circle center

    dirx = vx-x
    diry = vy-y

    Lx = cx - x
    Ly = cy - y

    tca = dot(Lx,Ly,dirx,diry)

    if tca < 0:
        return False

    Lsq = dot(Lx,Ly,Lx,Ly)
    tcasq = tca*tca
    
    dsq = Lsq - tcasq

    rsq = r*r

    if dsq>rsq:
        return False

    thc = math.sqrt(rsq-dsq)

    t0 = tca - thc

    t1 = tca + thc

    if t0 < 0: 
        t0 = t1
        if t0 < 0: 
            return False
            

    return True
```

Comment: Parametrize the ray as $(x,y) = (o_x,o_y) + t(v_x,v_y)$. Substitute that into equation of the circle $(x-c_x)^2+(y-c_y)^2 = r^2$, you get a quadratic equation in $t$. the **ray** intersect the circle iff the quadratic equation have **non-negative** roots. For your code, the mistake start at the first two lines, at the point you define $(dir_x,dir_y) = (v_x - x,v_y - v)$, this vector has no relation with any direction appear in the problem...

Comment: By applying a translation and rotation, the ray can assumed to be the x axis. Then it's just a matter of finding whether the circle intersects the x axis, which is trivial (is the y ordinate of the center in the interval (-r, r)?)

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be your mistake.
The lines

```
dirx = vx-x
diry = vy-y
```

should be

```
dirx = vx
diry = vy
```

since `vx` and `vy` are already direction vectors.

Comment: No idea why this got down-voted, since it works if you make this change..

Comment: Another thing is, make sure that your direction vector is normalized. Your variable tca is the scalar projection of L onto your direction vector using the dot product. If the length of dirx,diry is not 1, you are scaling tca and your calculation of dsq, the squared distance between the ray and the center of the circle will be wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a fine answer. It doesn't have much detail, but it doesn't need much since it's just pointing out a specific bug in the code.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Note ***boldface-italic*** variables are vectors, and *italic* variables are scalars. The $\cdot$ operator is the dot product.</sub>

1. Define ray as $\boldsymbol{r}(t) = \boldsymbol{o} + t\,\boldsymbol{e}$
2. Define circle center $\boldsymbol{c}$ and radius $R$
3. Find the distance along the ray closest to the center $$t = \boldsymbol{e}\cdot \left( \boldsymbol{c} - \boldsymbol{o} \right)$$
4. Find closest point on ray to the circle center $$ \boldsymbol{p} = \boldsymbol{o} + t\, \boldsymbol{e}$$
5. Check if points is inside the radius $$ \| \boldsymbol{p}-\boldsymbol{c} \|  \leq R $$

   An optimized way to do this is to check the square of the distance

   $$\left( \boldsymbol{p}-\boldsymbol{c}  \right) \cdot \left(\boldsymbol{p}-\boldsymbol{c}  \right) \leq R^2$$

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this more simple approach rather than the one you're using. You can do this by trying to analytically find the minimum distance between the points on the line and the centre of the circle.

Define the variable $\lambda$ by:

$$ \lambda = - \dfrac{(x-c_x)v_x + (y-c_y)v_y}{v_x^2 + v_y^2} $$

Now use lambda to calculate the variable below:

$$ r^* = \sqrt{(x + \lambda v_x - c_x)^2 + (y + \lambda v_y - c_y)^2} $$

$r^{*}$ is the minimum distance between the "ray" and the centre of the circle. Clearly if $r^* > r$, the line and the circle do not intersect.(You can derive the relation I provided for $\lambda$ by differentiating this equation and setting it to $0$.) Otherwise they intersect. If $r^* < r$ they intersect at two points. Since you're using Python the chances of $r^* = r$ is really low because of rounding errors, so the downside to this method is you likely won't be able to tell if the line is exactly tangent to the circle or not.

Answer (score 0):

You only asked for a code review, but since your question title asks "how to do it", here is a nice approach. The basic idea is what I said in my comment above - apply a translation and rotation to turn the ray into the positive x-axis, and then check (easily) whether the circle intersects the axis.

Say the ray's origin is $\mathbf{a} = (a_x, a_y)$, its direction vector is $\mathbf{v} = (v_x, v_y)$, the circle's center is $\mathbf{c} = (c_x, c_y)$ and its radius is $r$. Consider the rigid motion $F(P) = R(P - \mathbf{a})$, where $R$ is some matrix to be determined. I want it to be a rotation which sends the vector $\mathbf{v}$ to the x axis.

Naively I might try to choose $R$ to be a rotation, you can compute that the required rotation is $R = \pmatrix{a & -b \\ b & a}$, where

$$a = \frac{v_x}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}}\qquad b = \frac{-v_y}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2
}}$$

but that's kind of complicated, and I don't really care about the scale - so actually let's take $R = \pmatrix{v_x & v_y \\ -v_y & v_x}$.

The ray intersects the circle $C$ if and only if $F(C)$ intersects the positive x axis. That is equivalent to the claim that $F(\mathbf{c}) = (c_x', c_y')$ has $c_x > 0$ and $-r \le c_y \le r$.

It's easy to compute these numbers exactly:

\begin{align*}
c_x &= v_x(c_x-a_x) + v_y(c_y - a_y) \\
c_y &= -v_y(c_x-a_x) + v_x(c_y - a_y)
\end{align*}

So the algorithm reduces to: Compute these two numbers, and do three inequality checks.